# Is there any possibility to make my visualforce page visible in visualforce component only in specific conditions

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I have  a list of elements in my visualforce page that can sometime be empty. The visualforcepage is displayed in a visualforce component on the home page. I wonder if there is any possibility to hide the component if the list is empty.

```
 <apex:repeat var="a" value="{!accounts}">
                <apex:outputLabel for="link" value="{!a.Name} " />
 </apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `rendered` attribute. Something like

```html
<apex:repeat var "a" value="{!accounts}" rendered="{!NOT(AccountsEmpty)}">
    <apex:outputLabel for="link" value="{!a.name}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

and in your controller add the method:

```java
public boolean getAccountsEmpty(){
  return this.accounts == null || this.account.size() == 0;
}
```

EDIT: Adding how to also not render parent components/page

[Here is some in depth documentation on this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication) but put simply you need to add an attribute to your component with the repeat in it so you can pass in the page parent page/components apex controller for example if your parent page had a apex controller with the name `MyApexController`...

```html
<apex:attribute name="controller" description="parent page controller" type="MyApexController" assignTo="{!pageController}"/>
```

Then you can access its members with public getters and setters from within the component
Heres how that would look
**Parent Page Controller**

```java
public class MyApexController {
  public boolean hasAccounts {get; set;}

  public MyApexController(){
    //Your controller constructor
  }
}
```

**Child Components Apex controller**

```java
public class MyComponentsController {
  public List<Account> accounts {get; set;}
  public MyApexController pageController {get; set;} //this will get set by apex:attibute
  public MyComponentController(){
    if(getAccountsEmpty()){
      this.pageController.hasAccounts = false; //no accounts let parent page know
    } else {
      this.pageController.hasAccounts = true;
    }
  }

public boolean getAccountsEmpty(){
  return this.accounts == null || this.account.size() == 0;
}
```

Then on your parent page or component just add a similar attribute to your child component 
Parent page tag
`<apex:page rendered="{!hasAccounts}">`

or a parent component tag

`<apex:component rendered="{!hasAccounts}">`

Comment: This is really good but still the visualforce component is displayed on homepage but now is just blank. I want to also not have that displayed on the homepage at all

Comment: Him maybe you could add the same rendered attribute `rendered="{!NOT(AccountsEmpty)}"` to the main parent aura:component tag. I'm not sure if this will do exactly what you want but it's worth a try

Comment: What i said is that visualforce component (not page)is still on the home page. The Visualforcepage is not rendering anymre and that is really good. Now i want that the visualforce component where is attached, to not be displayed as well

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply... Still, a bit confused so just to clarify the `<apex:repeat>` from the question is inside a component (which is now not visible) which is then inside a Visualforce page (I've never heard of a page inside a component before which is what you're comment seems to suggest) and you now want the page to also not be rendered when the component is not rendered correct?

Comment: repeat is inside the visualforcepage .  And this visualforcepage is attached to the visualforce component (edit home page -> drag visualforce component on the homepage ). I want the whole component to dissapear if there are no accounts

Comment: Ok, I think you have those around the wrong way as Visualforce Components go inside of Visualforce pages and not the other way around but nevermind. It can be a bit of work to get parent pages to get information from their child components which I believe is what you need to do. I'll add to my answer what you can do.

Comment: You gave me the best solution, my bad was that i am not explaining this correct. I realized that the name of the "component" is lightning component. And that lightning component visualforce i added on homepage. And that's what i don't want to be displayed if the visualforce page does not have the accounts. :(.

Comment: Ahhhh ok thanks for clearing that up. Unfortunately, Hiding your visualforce component from home page is going to be extremely difficult if not impossible (I think & I may be wrong). When you add components to a home page via the lightning app builder you'll see there are filters available but for homepages these are limited to User, user permission & device filters which won't help much. You may be able to create a custom field on user and update it if the accounts are empty but as this would need to take place in the constructor and dml isn't allowed in there it may be impossible sorry

Comment: I made it possible by creating a field in user object. When there are no accounts that field is set to false after that  i set a trigger that checks if the field is or is not false. Thank you for input.